# Java hibernate SQL Null point exception

Tags: java, sql

I have the code below to execute SQL in a java method, im getting a `null: java.lang.NullPointerException` when running the code.

```
        public void addPrevious(TodaysDate Date){
                String paymentDate = ("SELECT PAYMENTDATE FROM table1  where DATE IN (SELECT ID FROM _DATE WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE ) ))");
                String reportingUnit = ("SELECT REPORTING_UNIT FROM table1  where DATE IN (SELECT ID FROM _DATE WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM _DATE ) ))");
                String insertLastDate =  ("INSERT INTO table1(PAYMENTDATE, REPORTING_UNIT, Date) VALUES  ("+paymentDate+", "+reportingunit+", "+asOfDate+")");

                getSession().createQuery(paymentDate);
                getSession().createQuery(reportingunit);

            }
```

I'm calling the code using the code below. I cant figure out where the null value is coming from, I tried debugging but the program crashes before getting anything useful

```
AdjustmentHibernate AdjustmentHibernate = new AdjustmentHibernate();
AdjustmentHibernate.addPrevious(asOfDate);
```

Comment: Maybe `getSession()` returns `null` ?

Comment: Please add the full StackTrace of that NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written/pasted your code correctly in the question then it could be your spelling mistake (i.e. **capital 'U' in "reportingUnit"**) in the below program statement:

```
getSession().createQuery(reportingUnit);
```